# Xna Intersect is to slow

Tags: c#, xna, collision

Hello i have a problem with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < map.collision_rects.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (player.collision_rect.Intersects(map.collision_rects[i]))
            {

                    Debug.WriteLine("INTERSERCTED:" + player.velocity.Y);
                    player.velocity.Y = 0;
                    player.has_jumped = false;



            }
        }
        player.Update(gameTime);
```

The problem is that it Detects that it intersected but the velocity is set to zero a frame later than it detected

```
 if (has_jumped == true)
        {
            float i = 1;
            velocity.Y += 0.15f*i;
        }
```

The code that sets the velocity

Comment: you are printing `velocity.Y` before it's set to 0. Move the writeline after `player.has_jumped == false`

Comment: okay thanks, such a dumb mistake :D

Comment: However the Intersects is still kinda slow and triggers some frames after it colided

Comment: Are you sure that it's the intersect that is slow, and not that it isn't tunneling before you check for collision?

Comment: `Update` and `Draw` have different time intervals. When you say "some frames later", you mean a few update cycles later? `Update` is synchronous, therefore `Intersect` is evaluated before the next update cycle. Are you sure your rectangles are correct?

Comment: Well the rectangles are correct, but i meant that it dete ts the intersection but the velocity is set to zero a little bit after and the player clips through the block.